# Pass Multiple Variable Types To a Single Variable Of a Class or a Function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, parameter-passing

I searched a lot and found that in kotlin we can't have a variable of multiple types simultaneously. Like in **typescript** we have

```
var name: Int | String = 5
```

Below is the problem, I have to use the same code twice and that is really not a good programming practice because I have to repeat it.

```
class Keyboard(private val context: Context, private val form: SomeBinding) {
    //some common functions
    fun startKeyboard() {
            theNumericPad()
            dot()
            backSpace()
            longPressBS()
        }
    }
```

The problem is I have to pass a different **Binding** in another use case which uses the same functions.

```
class Keyboard(private val context: Context, private val form: SomeBinding) {
    //some common functions
    fun startKeyboard() {
            theNumericPad()
            dot()
            backSpace()
            longPressBS()
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to pass different **binding** for different use cases. If Yes How? If not what else can I use to reuse the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kotlin `Any` is the parent for all types,

You can use param type as `Any` and then once you start using that parameter value, type check if trying to do something with `String` or `Int` or based on your type. It will solve your problem

Resource- https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/

Answer (score 0):

var variable : Any = 5
it will be working according to the value you assigned to it.
You can also go for conditional assignment depending on a logic
var v = if(a > 5) "big number" else "small number"
Just an example nothing else